# Calculating minimum s-t cuts is not implemented yet in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have been trying to simply get a mincut of the graph using the igraph package in R. I read some 60 rows from a "seeds" dataset available in the UCI datasets for machine learning under the category of Clustering, Classification. I am just trying to implement a semi-supervised method of classifying the unlabeled points (I deleberately made some changes in the dataset to suit my need).

I constructed a graph using some heuristic and I feel that the heauristic is working fine. But the problem arises when I compute the min-cut using graph.mincut function.

When I run this line

`# g is the graph I am using
graph.mincut(g, value.only = FALSE)`

It perfectly returns

```
$value
[1] 1

$cut
[1] 144

$partition1
[1] 24

$partition2
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
```

But when I give source and the target variables i.e.

```
graph.mincut(g, source = 1, target = 30, value.only = FALSE)
```

I get an error message saying

```
Error in graph.mincut(g, source = 1, target = 30, value.only = FALSE) : 
Calculating minimum s-t cuts is not implemented yet
```

If I give the below line

```
graph.mincut(g, source = 1, target = 30, value.only = TRUE)
```

I get the answer to be

```
[1] 11
```

I would be very grateful if somebody could guide me by telling where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to instead get the min cut with the `stMincuts` function from the `igraph` package:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(144)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10, .5, directed=TRUE)
cut <- stMincuts(g, source=1, target=4)
```

Now you can access the value:

```
cut$value
# [1] 4
```

the edges that were cut:

```
E(g)[cut$cuts[[1]]]
# Edge sequence:
#            
# [8]  1 -> 3
# [15] 1 -> 4
# [24] 1 -> 6
# [30] 1 -> 7
```

and the vertices in one partition:

```
V(g)[cut$partition1s[[1]]]
# Vertex sequence:
# [1] 1
```

If there are multiple cuts (there were two in the example I've provided here), you can get the edges/vertices with, for instance, `cut$cuts[[2]]` and `cut$partition1s[[2]]`, ...

Comment: Oh .. I forgot to mention that I am working with an undirected graph ... I see that stmincut requires the graph to be directed .. Correct me if I am wrong ...

Comment: @AnishV if your graph `g` is undirected, just compute a directed version with `dg <- as.directed(g)` and operate on `dg`.